# How to modify child item of a branch once I added an item into the bucket?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7.2

I have defined number of branches using same hierarchy but different layout.
I'm importing the data from the external source and creating items in a bucket programmatically. I obtain the reference to proper branch based on some logic and I use following code to create and add a branch item into my bucket:

```
BranchItem branch = News.GetNewsBranchItem(item.Genre);
if (branch == null)
{
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(string.Format("Missing branch for {} genre!", item.Genre), this);
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(string.Format("Failed to import import item id: {0}", item.Id.ToString()), this);
   return;
}
Item newlyCreatedBranch = parent.Add(ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(item.Title), branch);
```

Then I want to access branch first child which is actually news item I want to fill with the data and complete the action:

```
Item newsItem = newlyCreatedBranch.Children[0];
newsItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
newsItem[SCG.BasePage2.FieldIds.MetaKeywords] = item.Keywords;
.
.
.
newsItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

After process successfully finishes I do inspect the newly created items and found to my surprise that I'm missing content?!

I'm surprised because earlier I was accessing and filling my branch child node before

```
parent.Add(ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(item.Title), branch);
```

and noticed that the news item was properly filled ...
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It was late after long day hence silly question I posted above.
Well, following code return news item instead of branch item:

```
Item newlyCreatedBranch = parent.Add(ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(item.Title), branch);
```

Once I considered returned item, the item I want to fill problem was solved.
Commented code was not necessary:

```
Item newsItem = parent.Add(ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(item.Title), branch);
//Item newsItem = newlyCreatedBranch.Children[0];
```